# MCQ validation using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to check my mcq question in javascript. If the answer is the 4th one, it should alert "correct", else it should alert "wrong". Here is the code I have tried:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Problem</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate1(){
            one = document.getElementById("1");     
            two = document.getElementById("2");     
            three = document.getElementById("3");       

if ( (one.checked == true) || (two.checked ==  true) || (three.checked == true)  ){
    window.alert ('Wrong answer');
}
else {
    window.alert ('correct checked');
}   
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <h2 align="center">Problems on trains</h2><br></br>
    <form name="ques1" action="" method="post" onSubmit="return validate1();">

    <h5>1. A train running at the speed of 60 km/hr crosses a pole in 9 seconds. What is the length of the train? </h5>
    &nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp120<input type="radio" name="one" value="120" id="1"/>
    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp180<input type="radio" name="one" value="180" id="2"/>
    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp324<input type="radio" name="one" value="324" id="3"/>
    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp150<input type="radio" name="one" value="150" id="4"/>
    <input type="submit" value="check"/>
    </form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: PMI, but MCQ would be...?

Comment: multiple choice question

Comment: your submission contains no question.

Comment: Why not just do `if (four.checked) { // correct } else { // wrong }`

Comment: I have checked using that also.Still it is not showing the correct alert box

Comment: Can anyone answer me the correct code?